# How to use variable "sampler" in JSR223 Sampler (JMeter)

Tags: jmeter

I'm finding the way to use the variable `sampler` in JSR223 Sampler, JSR223 PreProcessor, JSR223 PostProcessor, and all other JSR223 script.

There are some other variables like `vars`, `props`, `prev`, `SampleResult`. I can use them easily.

For example:

- `vars`: vars.get("VARIABLE_NAME"), vars.put("VARIABLE_NAME","VALUE"), ...
- `props`: props.get, props.put, ...
- `prev`: prev.getTime(), prev.isSuccessful(), prev.getLatency(), ...
- `SampleResult`: SampleResult.getResponseCode(), SampleResult.getResponseMessage(), ...

But I don't know how to use variable `sampler`. Only thing I can do with this variable is:

`sampler.sample()`: It helps to returns the Name of current Sampler

So, could anyome please let me know there is any other way to use this variable?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For JSR223 Sampler `sampler` variable stands for [JSR223Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/sampler/JSR223Sampler.html), see the JavaDoc for all available methods and fields.

When it comes to JSR223 Pre or Post Processor - in that case `sampler` variable stands for **parent** sampler class instance, for instance in case of [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) it will be [HTTPSamplerProxy](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html), for [JDBC Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) - it will be [JDBCSampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/jdbc/sampler/JDBCSampler.html) and so on.

You can check exact class using Groovy expression like:

```
log.info(sampler.getClass().getName())
```

[image: Groovy sampler variable]

You can check [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on pre-defined variables and their usage. It is applicable for Groovy as well.

Comment: It's very helpful for your example. I hope you can give me some other sample so that I can see more the overall picture of this variable `sampler`. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`sampler` is a [Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/Sampler.html) object. you can use whatever the methods available here, not only methods declared in Sampler class but also the methods in super classes/interfaces like `TestElement`.

For example:

```
sampler.sample() - returns sampler's name
sampler.setProperty() - set a property by specifying key, value
sampler.setThreadName() - set thread name for the sampler.
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I took a lot of time to find some sample like this, but can you forgive me because I can only vote 1 answer. Anyway, I'm much appreciate your effort for answering my question.